# Standard ChannelFactory using CreateChannelWithActAsToken using wrong trust version to request ActAs token

Tags: wcf, binding, wif, ws-federation

When I use my security token to call factory.CreateChannelWithActAsToken it calls my STS's Issue using the wrong namespacing and expecting the wrong trustversion.

I can connect to my STS and request tokens and ActAs tokens manually with WSTrustChannel using WSTrust13 an it works perfectly fine. But when I setup a WS2007FederationHttpBinding and point to my STS it always makes the issue request using the wrong format. I stepped into my STS and had to deserialize the message using the WSTrustFeb2005ResponseSerializer instead of WSTrust13ResponseSerializer.

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
<binding name="AdministrationServiceBinding">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <message issuedTokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0" negotiateServiceCredential="false">
      <issuer address="https://localhost:44300/WSFederationServices.svc/Issue"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomSecurityTokenServiceBinding"  />
      <issuerMetadata address="https://localhost:44300/WSFederationServices.svc/mex" />
    </message>
  </security>
</binding>
</ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
```

I'm sure I probably am misunderstand how something works. But, this seems like it should work and is not. Any input?

Comment: I guess an easier way to clarify my question is whether there is a way to specify what trust version a standard ChannelFactory using a ws2007FederatedHttpBinding will make when it needs to call Issue for an ActAs token?

Is it something that it reads from the Issuer's Metadata? 
Is there a property on ws2007FederatedHttpBinding I have to set? 

Or do I have to implement the older 1.2 standard for all ActAs Issue requests?